# jQuery UI draggable containment offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a 800x400px div and inside of it I have a div with 20x20px size.

I'm using jQuery UI draggable with the containment option but I need to offset 20px off the sides of the parent div.

So the draggable area should really be 760x360px, centered in the 800x400px.

I know I could use another div, make it that size and put the smaller one on there but I need a solution that doesn't involve creating another div.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I can't use padding on the parent element because the div I'm dragging is absolute positioned.

Comment: u can add padding:20px to your parent div to achieve that

Comment: @VibinTV I forgot to mention that the div that it's being dragged is absolutely positioned

Comment: It is not possible to do it. You can limit the `draggable` area without padding by [containment](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) but at first, you need padding because this option applies on `draggable` element when it is dragged.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI Draggable `containment` option can take multiple types of inputs.

> **Multiple types supported:**
>
> - **Selector:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.
> - **Element:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
> - **String**: Possible values: `"parent"`, `"document"`, `"window"`.
> - **Array**: An array defining a bounding box in the form `[ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]`.

So this means you can get the `[x,y]` or `[left,top]` of the container object and then calculate the containment array.

```js
function getContainment($box, $drag, space) {
  var x1 = $box.offset().left + space;
  var y1 = $box.offset().top + space;
  var x2 = $box.offset().left + $box.width() - $drag.width() - space;
  var y2 = $box.offset().top + $box.height() - $drag.height() - space;
  return [x1, y1, x2, y2];
}
$("#draggable").draggable({
  containment: getContainment($(".container"), $("#draggable"), 20)
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #CCC;
}

#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
</div>
```